# Run job once at 8 PM and stop at 6 AM in Quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net, schedule

How can i schedule job to run once at 8:00 PM Every Day and force it to stop at 6:00 AM in next day?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446215/configuring-quartz-net-to-stop-a-job-from-executing-if-it-is-taking-longer-than

Comment: @derloopkat i need run once every day, question edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup trigger to run job every day at 8PM. If you prefer cron expressions, you can use [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com) UI for expression generation.
2. As @derloopkat mentioned, [Configuring Quartz.Net to stop a job from executing, if it is taking longer than specified time span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446215/configuring-quartz-net-to-stop-a-job-from-executing-if-it-is-taking-longer-than) shows approach how to stop job using `IInterruptableJob` interface. Moreover, cause you know exact time, when job should be stoped (6AM), you may not to use separate thread for `Interrupt`() method, but create another simple job that do interruption at 6AM by trigger.